# Algorithm for sharing folders between users

Tags: php

I'm creating some sort of "to do list" application in PHP. Now I want to implement function for sharing tasks between users, those tasks are basically folders. Can you give me some idea how can I give access to folder, only to some users. I wanted to use database but currently I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Why not use the database? And you want to use real folders?

Comment: Please use a database, using folders for this is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using a database, allow original task owner to assign other users to the task. As a *basic* example, you can create a 'task_group' table with a task id field. This will basically lead to each task having its own group in the database. Then create a 'task_group_users' table with a task_group_id field and a user_id field. You then check this table to see if user is part of the task_group by user id. Owner of task is able to add users to group by adding user id's to task_group_users.

This example can be extended further to support multiple groups per task by adding a group name field and permission level field within the task_group table.

This can be used for a backend for actual system folders, but I wouldn't use actual system groups. This could lead to security issues and will ultimately be limited.

Comment: Thank you. I have similar idea but with less databases. So I create 'users' table with user_id field, then I create 'tasks' table with 'task_id' field. Then I create third table 'users_tasks' where I store user_id and task_id. This is mysql normalization, so every user can have more tasks a single task can be assigned to more than one user. Is this good approach?

Comment: Sorry, I meant tables not databases. One database with a user table, task table, task_group table, and task_group_user table. I'm pretty sure that would be the best norm form, especially if you might eventually have more than one group per task, such as editor group, developer group, admins etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store all data in MySQL database for example? It's going to be much easier to delegate access rules there.

At other had you can allow access to this folders only trough PHP-script, and in this PHP script check if user has enough privileges to access that folder.

Your question is very ambigous in this formulation.

Comment: That was my idea too, but thing is, user can create one task, then he can grant access to this task for another user, now two users have access to this task. That's where my problem is. I don't have idea how to implement function where one user can grant access to task for another user.